# Convert HH:MM:SS into seconds in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to convert times into seconds aka:

```
00:25:56 = 25 * 60 + 56 = 1556
01:00:00 = 1 * 60 * 60 = 3600
```

I had been using: `date -d$element +%s` but this of course returns the current date and time in seconds.

Comment: I think there is an error in your examples. `00:24:56 = 25 * 60 + 56 = 1556` should be either `00:24:56 = 24 * 60 + 56 = 1496` or `00:25:56 = 25 * 60 + 56 = 1556`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply specify the starting date of Unix time (also known as "Epoch") in the UTC time zone (shorthand `Z`):

```
time=00:24:56
date -d "1970-01-01 $time Z" +%s
# prints 1496
```

Comment: Genius!  Indeed!...  Now I will need to solve why: `realTime= date -d "1970-01-01 $element Z" +%s____
echo $realTime // 600 ____
       FILE_CONTENTS="$FILE_CONTENTS$realTime"` FILE_CONTENTS === "" //empty string

Comment: I don't understand your comment due to formatting issues. But it looks like you meant `realtime=$(date ...)` when you actually wrote  `realtime= date ...`. I recommend https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Oh interesting. For variable definitions that aren't just simple remappings you need to wrap! Indeed, this is likely the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The title says *in Bash*, so I’m going to assume that no external tools (such as `date`) are allowed. At which point I would do something old-fashioned — like a calculation with a base-60 number:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
shopt -s extglob

to_seconds() {
  local -a digits
  IFS=: digits=($1)
  local -air digits=("${digits[@]##+(0)}")  # else ^0 means octal
  local -i i="$((${#digits[@]} - 1))" result=0 order=1
  for ((;;)); do
    ((result += digits[i] * order)) || :
    ((--i < 0)) && break || :
    ((order *= 60))
  done
  echo "$((result))"
}
```

As a side note, the `base#number` integer syntax is easy to find in the Bash `man` page, but I have never found a way to (ab)use it nicely. On the other hand, there is always an obvious and ugly way to use that syntax:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
shopt -s extglob

declare -ar DIGITS=({0..9} {a..z} {A..X})

to_seconds() {
  local -a digits
  IFS=: digits=($1)
  local -air digits=("${digits[@]##+(0)}")  # else ^0 means octal
  local -i digit
  local result=
  for digit in "${digits[@]}"; do
    result+="${DIGITS[digit]}"
  done
  echo "$((60#"$result"))"  # Magic! Ugliness!
}
```

Examples:

```sh
to_seconds 01:09:09  # 4149
to_seconds 01:11:09  # 4269
to_seconds 23:09:00  # 83340
to_seconds 00:59:59  # 3599
to_seconds 00:09:09  # 549
to_seconds 11:09:09  # 40149
to_seconds 23:59:59  # 86399
```

Answer (score 1):

Without other commands than bash it-self:

```sh
DATE=00:24:56
HH=${DATE:0:2}; HH=${HH#0}
MM=${DATE:3:2}; MM=${MM#0}
SS=${DATE:6:2}; SS=${SS#0}
SECONDS=$(( ( ( HH * 60 ) + MM ) * 60 + SS ))
echo $SECONDS
```